# Importing MapInfo TABLE data into QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, mapinfo

When I import MapInfo files into QGIS only the shapes of the MapInfo elements are imported and not the associated table data. How does one retain the Table data saved in the .DAT file?

I have a series of MapInfo contour files. I can import the shapes, but the altitude for each of the shapes cannot be loaded in. How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

MapInfo TAB files can be opened directly (not imported) and the table data will be available.  If you have mixed topology in the TAB QGIS will ask you which type to open. Try dragging the .TAB file onto the QGIS map and see what happens - let us know the know the result.